# How to make vi/vim execute "rewrite filter on write" for given file extension?

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I would like to be able to write handy "short version" in configuration file.

The obvious way to achieve it would be "on save filter" executed by vi/vim.
The filter script would rewrite "short version" to "long version" expected by the app.

Comment: Use the bufwritepre autocommand

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Could you turn your comment to answer?  I am willing to accept it (after test).  At first glance it seems to be what I asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `code` is an ex command that does your filtering (which could be calling a vimscript function, a simple `%substitute`, or even a complex external filter with `%!`), you can do something like

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/myfiletype.vim
augroup FilterOnSave
  autocmd! * <buffer>
  autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> code
augroup END
```